# Is it possible for a Couchbase node to have a document been indexed and persisted by a MR view while the document itself haven't been persisted yet?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

If the answer is yes, it means that only the index could survive a blackout and the document itself will be lost after a blackout. Will Couchbase do anything like delete such index while restarting the node or just left the node inconsistent?

If the answer is no, any information would be appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer your question but suggests that the scenario you describe is possible:
http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Views/views-storedData.html

You could ensure that this doesn't happen by forcing persistence to disc at write time.